# Equal Height Columns using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do some sort of tryptic where the first item in a list takes a bit more prominence over the second and third.

I've got it to the point where I'm adding the height of second and third and applying said height to the first item. But in trying to fool-proof the design, I need it to play nice in reverse.

For example, if the height of the first item is of greater value than the second+third item combined then apply the difference somewhere (second or third)...sorry if this all seems confusing.

Here is the code: http://codepen.io/randydaniel/pen/uKkfb

```
var equalHeights = function(cols) {

$(cols).each(function() {
  var colTwo = parseInt($('#blog-listing li:nth-child(2)').css('height').replace("px", "")),
    colThree = parseInt($('#blog-listing li:nth-child(3)').css('height').replace("px", ""));

    var extra = colTwo + colThree;
    $(cols).css('height',extra);
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  equalHeights($("#blog-listing li:first-child"));
});
```

Disclaimer: I'm not too knowledgeable with javascript as I am re-purposing some code from a prior example and flexbox (if possible) isn't an option at the moment.

Comment: You don't need the replace, `parseInt` will find the number in the string either way.

Comment: What kind of browser support are you aiming for? If you can use Flexbox, this is super easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using jquery you could do this

```
    var equalHeights = function(cols) {

    $(cols).each(function() {
      var colTwo = $('#blog-listing li:nth-child(2)').height();
      var colThree = $('#blog-listing li:nth-child(3)').height();
      var colOne = $('#blog-listing li:nth-child(1)').height();

      var extra = colTwo + colThree;
      if(extra > colOne){
        $(cols).height(extra);
      }else{
        // split the difference between nodes height
        var split = (colOne - extra)/2;
        $('#blog-listing li:nth-child(2)').height(colTwo+split)
        $('#blog-listing li:nth-child(3)').height(colThree+split)
      }
  });
  };

  $(document).ready(function() {
    equalHeights($("#blog-listing li:first-child"));
  });
```

Comment: Thanks BenjaminDavid! This seems to work flawlessly. Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to help. Jquery height() method should help with cross browser differences as well.